# What Chinese podcasts are available to improve my listening skills?

Tags: mandarin, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese)

I'm a big podcast fan, and I think listening to Chinese podcasts would be a great way to improve my listening skills. I enjoy listening to [慢速中文](http://www.slow-chinese.com/), but I've already listen to all the podcasts they put out.

I'm looking for something at the upper intermediate level that covers a range of topics - I really like the way 慢速中文 covers anything they think is interesting, is well produced, and features a selection of great music as well...

Does anyone have good suggestions for Chinese podcasts I should check out? What Chinese podcasts have you found to both good for your listening skills, and interesting to listen to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried chinesepod.com?  They have podcasts on a variety of different topics across a range of different levels.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of material is your favorite,but you can try to search "有声小说"，there are a lot of audio novels in the results.I recommend a novel with the name"明朝那些事",it is about the history of Ming dynasty, and it's popular in China.

Answer (score 1):

How about 新浪新闻? You can view latest TV news from CCTV etc from this podcast. It could be boring though.